# Why duality of confidence interval and hypothesis testing fails in random effect test for presence random effect?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, mixed-model, confidence-interval

I am reading Faraway's Extending the linear model with R chapter 10 section 2.

"In this case, the lower bound is zero. This is not surprising given our earlier
uncertainty over whether there really is a difference between the operators. In simpler
circumstances, there is a duality between confidence intervals and hypothesis tests in
that the outcome of a test can be determined by whether the point null hypothesis
lies within the confidence interval. Unfortunately, ***this duality does not apply in all
circumstances, this being a case in point.*** "

The example was to show that confidence interval cannot be used to test presence of random effect.

Why does duality of hypothesis testing and confidence interval fail in random effect detection? I would expect there are some magical statistics which will measure random effect to allow this duality.